# Th code of Counter(expression) confused me - from the book "Data Science from Scratch: First Principles with Python"

Tags: python

```
from collections import Counter
grades = [83, 95, 91, 87, 70, 0, 85, 82, 100, 67, 73, 77, 0]

# Bucket grades by decile, but put 100 in with the 90s
histogram = Counter(min(grade // 10 * 10, 90) for grade in grades)
```

And then he creates a histogram using the matplotlib library. I don't understand if it's a list comprehension because he uses `for grades in grades` and I also don't understand the use of min() here

Comment: The `min` is to make sure that any number over 90 gets a value of 90 - try `min(123 // 10 * 10, 90)` for example. Yes it is a comprehension, although not a list comprehension. What that line of code is doing is "flooring" the grade to a multiple of 10 with none of the "floored" values exceeding 90

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following rounds the grade to the lower decimal:

```
grade // 10 * 10
```

The use of `min` here is to put the grade of 100 together with the count of 90s grades

And it is not a list comprehension because it is missing the square brackets but it is a generator expression to pass the generator to the Counter which will then count the number of grades for each of the 10 percentiles